# UILabel sizeToFit breaking apart numbers

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel that is displaying an array of numbers in a vertical line; however, it is breaking apart numbers that are two or more digits into separate lines. How can I solve this?

```
syllableArr = ["6", "5", "5", "11"]

func updateSyllableLabel() {

    //Updates content of syllable label

    let multiLineString = self.syllableArr.joined(separator: "\n")
    syllableLabel.text = multiLineString
    syllableLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    syllableLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    syllableLabel.sizeToFit()
}
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of what this code produces]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Increase the width of the `UILabel`, you can either use `NSString` `size(attributes)` method to get the calculated length of your string or simply ensure your `UILabel` is long enough to contain any length of string it will take in. You can also set the `UILabel` property `numberOfLines` to 1 so that there will be no word wrapping, then set the property `adjustFontSizeToFitWidth` to true and the string will shrink to fit into your label.

Comment: Use syllableLabe.numberOfLines = 4.

Answer (score 0):

Set label width,height and set number of lines

```
  let syllableArr = ["6", "5", "5", "11"]
  let multiLineString = syllableArr.joined(separator: "\n")
  let syllableLabe = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 10, height: 80)) x,y width and height set according you

  syllableLabe.text = multiLineString
  syllableLabe.numberOfLines = 4
  syllableLabe.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
  print(“label text ===%@",syllableLabe.text!)
```

Out Put is

```
   label text ===%@6
                  5
                  5
                  11

 if you want to break 11 
 let str: String = syllableArr[3]
 str = ""11"
 let digits = String(str).characters.map { Int(String($0))! }
 print("digits is ---%@",digits) and create new array as this
 let newsyllableArr = ["6", "5", "5", "1","1"] and use same logic above
```